# How to export an Angular template that includes the interpolated values?

Tags: angular

I want to generate dynamic PDF's from templates written as angular components. For that I'm using puppeteer in my backend, which, for generating PDF's only accepts strings (afaik anyways).

This is the function I use to create the PDF-Template components:

```ts
getStringTemplate<T>(component: ComponentType<T>, config: PdfTemplatesConfig<string>): string {
  const injector = this.createInjector(config)
  const cmp = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component).create(injector);
  cmp.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  const tpl = cmp.location.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  cmp.destroy();
  return tpl;
}
```

The template is used to interpolate the injected value.

#### HTML Template

```html
<p>{{ config.data }}</p>
```

This is the result, when I use the function:

```html
<p _ngcontent-pdj-c166=""></p>
```

Is there another way to get the templates as a string **including** the interpolated values (i.e. the `{{ config.data }}`? I've made it work with nunjucks in my backend, but if exporting the angular templates would work, that would save me a lot of effort.

Thanks in advance

Comment: interesting. are you using Angular Universal ?

Comment: No I'm not using Angular Universal.